# Windows PowerShell equivalent of Linux `ls -l`

Tags: powershell, ls

Is there some way in PowerShell to emulate the behavior of the Linux `ls -l` command?

I would like to see what symbolic links point to.  Specifically, I used the PowerShell `New-Symlink` utility and I want to know where the -Path is on disk.

(Yes, I know the -Path because I created it myself, but I've wanted an `ls -l` equivalent on several other occasions.)

Answer (score 8):

With PowerShell v. 6 and above it is now built-in that `Get-ChildItem` will show symbolic links with their target location.

[Get-ChildItem Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1#parameters)

For emulating Linux `ls -l` you can do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem | Format-Table Mode, @{N='Owner';E={(Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner}}, Length, LastWriteTime, @{N='Name';E={if($_.Target) {$_.Name+' -> '+$_.Target} else {$_.Name}}}
```

This matches the column order of `ls -l` and also adds the file owner which `Get-ChildItem` doesn't show. If the file is a symlink, it will show in Mode column with `l` and the file name with show like so:

filename.txt -> c:\Users\joe\filename.txt

Here my functional version which I aliased to `ll` and added to my profile:

```
function Get-ChildItemUnix {
    Get-ChildItem $Args[0] |
        Format-Table Mode, @{N='Owner';E={(Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner}}, Length, LastWriteTime, @{N='Name';E={if($_.Target) {$_.Name+' -> '+$_.Target} else {$_.Name}}}
}
New-Alias ll Get-ChildItemUnix
```

Output shows like so:
[image]

Comment: Excelent, this did the job for me, I need to know how to add Terminal-Icons to the output, it is possible?

Answer (score 3):

It seems powershell does not support this out of the box. [Here's an article explaining how to use `dir` in PowerShell to show if there is a symbolic link, but it doesn't show the target of the link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/02/10/viewing-junctions-with-dir.aspx). To show the target of a link you have two options. First use `fsutil reparsepoint query` or use `dir` from the command prompt. Both have drawbacks. The first gives you the target path as hex data and the second must be run from the command prompt as powershell aliases `dir` to `Get-ChildItem` which doesn't show symlinks.

Try this

```
Get-ChildItem | % { fsutil reparsepoint query $_ }
cmd /c dir /a:l
```

The best answer I could come up with is the following (use the regex matching groups to extract more information if required):

```
$PATH="C:\tmp"
cmd /c dir $PATH | ? { $_ -match '([\d\.]+)\s+([\d:]+)\s+(\S+)\s+([^\[]+)\s*\[?([^\]]*)\]?' } | % { New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{Name=$matches[4];Target=$matches[5]}}
```

The Output will look similar to this

```
Target                                                      Name
------                                                      ----
                                                            .
                                                            ..
                                                            file.txt
C:\tmp\file.txt                                             symlink.txt
```