# How to add Terminal-Icons to a powershell function

Tags: powershell, terminal, window, windows-terminal, powershell-7.3

I have this function:

```
function Get-ChildItemUnix {
    Get-ChildItem $Args[0] |
        Format-Table Mode, @{N='Owner';E={(Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner}}, Length, LastWriteTime, @{N='Name';E={if($_.Target) {$_.Name+' -> '+$_.Target} else {$_.Name}}}
}
New-Alias ll Get-ChildItemUnix
```

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887324/windows-powershell-equivalent-of-linux-ls-l/65932616#65932616)

The thing is that I can see thar I want to show Icons in the result of the function like the ls command

[image]

The ll personalized command result is this

[image]

Comment: The formatting of your prompt string implies that you're using a custom library to achieve such formatting. Presumably, it is that custom library that modifies the default `Get-ChildItem` output format to include the icons of interest - PowerShell _itself_ does _not_ do that. Thus, you'll need to borrow that custom library's technique for injecting the icons and include it in your `Format-Table` command. As an aside: by baking a `Format-*` call into your `ll` / `Get-ChildItemUnix` command, you're making its output suitable _for display only_, and unsuited to _programmatic processing_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unicode characters like  and  as you use any other character like 'a' or 'b' as long as the underlying font includes them.

A small example that you can build from is the following. Printing names of the content of the current directory with with a different symbol depending whether it is a file or a folder.

```
PS> Get-ChildItem | 
      Format-Table @{N='Name'
                     E={if ($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
                          " $($_.Name)"
                        } else {
                          " $($_.Name)"
                        }}}

Name
----
 my-folder
 my-file
```